# AppBarLayout does not fill screen width (on real device)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

My appbar doesn't fill the screen on a real device, but does in the preview.

Preview (that's what I want):

[image]

On my Samsung S5:

[image]

You can see that the bar is not filling the screen's width (little space left and right).

Here is my xml-code:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/appBlue"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                >
                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                  android:text="test"
                    />
                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="test"
                    />
                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="test"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**EDIT**

I found the solution. The layout that is being replaced with my fragment I posted hat a padding. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have paddings set on the parent layout?

Comment: I have no paddings set

Comment: Show the `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and if there is a theme set for it, show the theme from `styles.xml`

Comment: can you please post the complete layout

Comment: I updated my post and added the Manifest file and the complete layout (Fragment)

Comment: Found the solution. Thx to you guys. Helped me